# scala : Type inference on a class member

Tags: type-inference, scala-3

Consider the following code : [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bq0H1t0qQCm5bVnNxqvk6g)

```scala
class A           {              }
class B extends A { def m = true }

trait X           { def obj : A     }
class Y extends X { def obj = new B }

val y = new Y
y.obj.m // Compiles in scala2, does not compile in scala3.
```

What is the type of `y.obj` ?

It appears that in *scala2* `y.obj` is a `B`, while in *scala3* `y.obj` is a `A` !
As a result looking up for `y.obj.m` compiles in scala2, but not in scala3.

Apparently, in scala3, the type of the abstract member `def obj: A` in `X` takes precedence over the narrower type inference in `Y`.

As expected, `y.obj` is a `B` when :

```scala
class Y /* extends X */ { def obj     = new B } // member is not previously declared
class Y    extends X    { def obj : B = new B } // type is forced by ascription
```

This looks benign, until one uses [transparent inline methods](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/metaprogramming/inline.html#transparent-inline-methods) to ship back some type information out of a macro.

- Is the discrepancy between *scala2* and *scala3* expected ?
- What is the intention ?
- Is there a workaround ?

Here is a more descriptive snippet: [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/8JeQ1cB1R66fQArp4tarjw)

```scala
class A
class B extends A:
  def m = true

transparent inline def choose(b: Boolean): A =
  if b then new A else new B


class X:
  def obj1 : A
  def obj2 : A
  def obj3 : A

class Y extends X:
  def obj1     = choose(true)  // type A
  def obj2     = choose(false) // type A ( from X.this.obj2 )
  def obj3 : B = choose(false) // type B ( from ascription  )
  def obj4     = choose(false) // type B ( from inference   )

val y = new Y
y.obj1.m // compile error     EXPECTED
y.obj2.m // compile error   UNEXPECTED
y.obj3.m // compiles          EXPECTED
y.obj4.m // compiles          EXPECTED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the discrepancy between *scala2* and *scala3* expected ?

**Yes**. [Here](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/7212) is the intention.

Is there a workaround ?

- **Yes**. Declaring the member as `final` prevents the widening.
- *However*, `final val` is expected to be [phased out](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/7212) from scala3, superseded by `inline val`.
- `inline def` compiles correctly, but also inlines the definition-rhs at the call site, which may not be the intention.
- `inline val` is restricted to literal constants.

A SIP about a `precise` modifier is in discussion [here](https://github.com/scala/improvement-proposals/pull/48).